# TFS 2010 make change to local copy

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2010  I have a project and I want to make only a local change to it and not check it in. I don't have edit privileges on the project. I tried removing the read only from the project but it will not work(will not allow me to edit). Is there an alternative ?

Comment: What sort of changes do you want to make, changes to the project structure or changes to a file within the project?

Comment: Adding new files to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check out a file before you can edit it.  Once you are done, just "Undo" that change (right-click and undo).  If you're wanting to add a new file, it's the same thing.  Add the file, then undo the change without checking in.

Remember, adding files is a "local" operation.  They are marked as a pending add until you actually commit them to the server by checking in.

Comment: In VSS you could remove the read only attribute and make the changes. You would not have to worry about the permissions. Is a similar thing possible ?.

Comment: There's the way you can do it, and the way you "should" do it.  I'm a big fan of not messing with the readonly attribute, as it can really start confusing the server when you try to get latest.  But you probably can remove the readonly attribute and edit the file singly (outside of Visual Studio).  Also, make sure in Tools->Options->Source Control->Environment that you don't have "get everythng when a solution or project is opened" checked.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have made your changes, if you really don't want to check them in, but, you want to preserve them, create a shelveset to store your changes.  This way, you can undo your changes so you don't always have them checked out and then if someone else changes the project, you can get latest, and then unshelve your changes to see how they work with the new code.